# I have input a reference image and it wont rotate. What do i do?

Tags: image, transform-orientation

So i am trying to create an image and i have input a reference image but i cannot rotate it on at 90 degrees on the Y-axis. I have changed all transformation orientation to Global but it isn't trying to work.

Answer (score 1):

Press ">", than choose "median point". Make sure "only location" is not selected.